# how to package UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have create a UIViewController, e.g DemoTableViewController, and want to reuse it in other project. Instead of copying source file of controller, I need to create a library to reuse it, however, after I create a static library containing DemoTableViewController, and set the class of a view controller in storyboard, there's a an error:

```
Unknown class DemoTableViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

[image]

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom class field on the right top, you can see that you have given it as `DemoTableViewController` instead of `DemoViewController`(Assuming that what you have mentioned in question as `DemoViewController` is the class name you have given to this custom class). Change that and then check. It should work.

If the above is not working, make sure you have copied the `DemoTableViewController.h` file to your current project and this library is added to target settings -> Linked frameworks and libraries.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have changed my question.

Comment: Copy the file `DemoTableViewController.h` to your project along with library and import it wherever required.